# Simplest way to add data to Firebase with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked at previous posts and the documentation and other resources, but I just cannot fiugre out how to add an entry to my firebase database when a button is clicked. The button calls writeNewPost(). Here is what I tried

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" onclick="writeNewPost()">Submit</button>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: MYAPIKEY,
    authDomain: MYDOMAIN,
    databaseURL: MYURL,
    projectId: MYPROJECT,
    storageBucket: STORAGEBUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: SENDERID
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script>
    function writeNewPost() {
      var postData = {
        "Name": "Brett"
      };

     var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;

     var updates = {};
     updates['/' + newPostKey] = postData;

     return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
   }
</script>
```

All I want is to have "Name":"Brett" under the root.

Comment: So that's basically from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: Yeah. Almost straight from it.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code... beside letting me wonder if  `'/' + newPostKey` is the right path...

Comment: Humm... is your button calling that function at all? Cause I think, the way you put it - that the function in undefined at `onclick="writeNewPost()"` Have you tried to put a `console.log("CALLED!")` inside your `writeNewPost`?

Comment: Yes. I just tested that and it is being called.

Comment: Any other errors in console?

Comment: No, and all the api data is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems quite good. To get you going with simple communication with Firebase you first need to **set some rules** https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

P.S: used your code, added rules into `Database → Rules(Tab)` and it works.

> **Disclaimer**!! use the below only for a limited test period of time - since it opens your database to the public - And read always the warnings that might appear in the panel!

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart):

> *It is essential that you configure these rules correctly before launching your app to ensure that your users can only access the data that they are supposed to.*

---

The way you presented your code - the inline `onclick=` points to a function that is only defined **later** in your code - therefore you're at risk of it being `undefined`.

A better way to keep your JS in one place.
Remove the inline `onclick` and add an `ID` selector like `id="submitPost"`

```
<button id="submitPost" type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Submit</button>
```

Than inside your script use:

```
document.getElementById("submitPost").addEventListener("click", writeNewPost);
```

Comment: Please always accompany such advice by a disclaimer to only do this for a limited amount of time, since it opens the database up for abuse by any user.

Comment: This still doesn't work. Btw, my database is empty. I'm trying to add to it. So I am trying to place a key-value pair under the root.

Comment: @brett my hands are tied. I used your code modified with my suggestion to make it work, created a firebase Project, set the test rules, clicked the button and I got directly under root your name key/value data stored. Is there something I'm missing?